# Cannot ADD CONSTRAINT in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having trouble with what I would think is a pretty simple constraint issue in postgres.

Ruinning:

`ALTER TABLE rss_feed_list ADD CONSTRAINT status_type CHECK (feed_status = 'active' OR feed_status 'inactive');`

returns the error:

ERROR:  type "feed_status" does not exist

Comment: You missed equals sign here: `feed_status 'inactive'` ?

Comment: I hate myself and I want to die =D  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equals sign here:

```
OR feed_status 'inactive'
```

It probably should be:

```
OR feed_status = 'inactive'
```